# Using raw Postgresql queries in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

First of all, I'm not a native English speaker, so excuse me if I make any mistakes related to my writing.

I'm starting as a dev and I was told that I should use a Postgresql query to accomplish a specific task in Ruby on Rails. This is the query:

> ORDER BY array_position(ARRAY[1, 2, 3], spree_products.id)

The goal is to show a view with different Spree products (probably the "ARRAY[1,2,3, etc]" part) of the database ordered in the same way they are placed in an input of an admin form.

Anyway, my question is more simple than that.

I understand this query is raw Postgresql, using an array_position function

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-array.html

I just want to know how can I implement this kind of raw queries in Rails. It probably has to be in an .rb file, but I don't really understand how, since query methods used in Rails (.order, for example) are much more common to see being used (that's what I commonly use), but apparently, here I should use raw Postgresql mixed with Rails.

Can you give me some examples and/or a basic documentation, please? I know the basics of both languages, but I've never mixed them in this way, so that's what is probably confusing me the most.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a scope and use `arel` wrap the array function `array_position`

```rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord

  scope :order_ids, ->(arr_ids) {
    order(Arel.sql("array_position(ARRAY#{arr_ids}, id::integer)"))
  }
end
```

now you could query as below

```rb
Product.order_ids([3,2,1])
Product.where(active: true).order_ids([3,2,1]).limit(10)
# ...
```

Comment: `"array_position(ARRAY#{arr_ids}, id::integer)"` is a SQL injection vulnerability and should only be used if `arr_ids` is not user input.

Comment: This can be addressed by adding `ActiveRecord::Base::sanitize_sql(arr_ids)` if it's possible that they are user input.